# Find the equilibrium point in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider this array:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])
```

I want to get the element that divides the array evenly, i.e the sum of array before the element equals the sum of the array after it. In this case, the 4th element `a[3]` divides the array evenly. Is there a faster (numpy) way to do that? Or do I have to iterate over all elements?

desired function:

```
f(a) =  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all input values are nonnegative, it seems likely that one of the most efficient ways to do this would be to build a cumulative sum array, then binary search it for the location with half the sum on either side. However, it's also really easy to get such a binary search wrong. While trying to get a binary search working on all edge cases, I wound up with the following tests:

```
class SplitpointTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFloatRounding(self):
        # Due to rounding error, the cumulative sums for these inputs are
        # [1.1, 3.3000000000000003, 3.3000000000000003, 5.5, 6.6]
        # and [0.1, 0.7999999999999999, 0.7999999999999999, 1.5, 1.6]
        # Note that under default settings, numpy won't display
        # enough precision to see that.
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint([1.1, 2.2, 1e-20, 2.2, 1.1]))
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint([0.1, 0.7, 1e-20, 0.7, 0.1]))

    def testIntRounding(self):
        self.assertEquals(1, splitpoint([1, 1, 1]))
    def testIntPrecision(self):
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint([2**60, 1, 1, 1, 2**60]))
    def testIntMax(self):
        self.assertEquals(
            2,
            splitpoint(numpy.array([40, 23, 1, 63], dtype=numpy.int8))
        )

    def testIntZeros(self):
        self.assertEquals(
            4,
            splitpoint(numpy.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int))
        )
    def testFloatZeros(self):
        self.assertEquals(
            4,
            splitpoint(numpy.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=float))
        )
```

And I went through the following versions before deciding it wasn't worth it:

```
def splitpoint(a):
    c = numpy.cumsum(a)
    return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2)
    # Fails on [1, 1, 1]

def splitpoint(a):
    c = numpy.cumsum(a)
    return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2.0)
    # Fails on [2**60, 1, 1, 1, 2**60]

def splitpoint(a):
    c = numpy.cumsum(a)
    if c.dtype.kind == 'f':
        # Floating-point input.
        return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2.0)
    elif c.dtype.kind in ('i', 'u'):
        # Integer input.
        return numpy.searchsorted(c, (c[-1]+1)//2)
    else:
        # Probably an object dtype. No great options.
        return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2.0)
    # Fails on numpy.array([63, 1, 63], dtype=int8)

def splitpoint(a):
    c = numpy.cumsum(a)
    if c.dtype.kind == 'f':
        # Floating-point input.
        return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2.0)
    elif c.dtype.kind in ('i', 'u'):
        # Integer input.
        return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]//2 + c[-1]%2)
    else:
        # Probably an object dtype. No great options.
        return numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2.0)
    # Still fails the floating-point rounding and zeros tests.
```

---

I could probably get this working if I kept trying, but it wouldn't be worth it. chw21's second solution, the one based on explicitly minimizing the absolute difference between the left and right sums, is much easier to reason about and more generally applicable. With the addition of `a = numpy.asarray(a)`, it passes all above test cases and also the following tests, which expand the kind of inputs the algorithm is expected to work on:

```
class SplitpointGeneralizedTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testNegatives(self):
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint([-1, 5, 2, 4]))
    def testComplex(self):
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint([1+1j, -5+2j, 43, -4+3j]))
    def testObjectDtype(self):
        from fractions import Fraction
        from decimal import Decimal
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint(map(Fraction, [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4])))
        self.assertEquals(2, splitpoint(map(Decimal, [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4])))
```

Unless it is specifically found to be too slow, I would go with chw21's second solution. In the slightly modified form in which I tested it, that would be the following:

```
def splitpoint(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    c1 = a.cumsum()
    c2 = a[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
    return np.argmin(np.abs(c1-c2))
```

---

The only flaw I can see is that if the input has an unsigned dtype and there is no index that exactly splits the input, this algorithm might not return the index that is closest to splitting the input, since `np.abs(c1-c2)` doesn't do the right thing for unsigned data types. It was never specified what the algorithm should do if there is no splitting index, so this behavior is acceptable, though it might be worth making a note about `np.abs(c1-c2)` and unsigned dtypes in a comment. If we want the index closest to splitting the input, we can get it at the cost of some extra runtime:

```
def splitpoint(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    c1 = a.cumsum()
    c2 = a[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
    if a.dtype.kind == 'u':
        # np.abs(c1-c2) doesn't work on unsigned ints
        absdiffs = np.where(c1>c2, c1-c2, c2-c1)
    else:
        # c1>c2 doesn't work on complex input.
        # We also use this case for other dtypes, since it's
        # probably faster.
        absdiffs = np.abs(c1-c2)
    return np.argmin(absdiffs)
```

And of course, here's the test for this behavior, which the modified form passes and the unmodified form fails:

```
class SplitpointUnsignedTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testBestApproximation(self):
        self.assertEquals(1, splitpoint(numpy.array([5, 5, 4, 5], dtype=numpy.uint32)))
```

Comment: Just for the sheer amount of work that you put into a single answer I have to upvote you ;)

Comment: That's awesome work. I salute you for this. I will accept this answer because it is the most complete account on the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for something like this:

```
def equib(a):
    c = a.cumsum()
    return np.argmin(np.abs(c-(c[-1]/2)))
```

First, we build the cumulative sum of `a`. Cumsum means that `c[i] = sum(a[:i])`. Than we look where the absolute value the difference between the values and the total weight becomes minimal.

**Update** @DSM noticed that my first version had a little offset, so here's another version:

```
def equib(a):
    c1 = a.cumsum()
    c2 = a[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
    return np.argmin(np.abs(c1-c2))
```

Comment: Almost, you should np.abs the substraction (otherwise you get the first element as the minimum)

Comment: @agomcas I noticed as soon as I hit enter.

Comment: The updated version still returns 2 on the OP's example when it should return 3, because it can't distinguish between the first 2 and the second ( in the argument to `argmin`, I mean.)

Comment: @chw21: Your method is at least twice as fast, if not for that "distinguish" problem

Comment: I'd recommend using `searchsorted` to search `c` for `c[-1] / 2`.

Comment: Combining chw21 and user2357112: np.searchsorted(a.cumsum(), a.sum()/2.)

Comment: You should store the `cumsum` in variable, and use `c[-1]` instead of `sum` for speed.

Comment: @user2357112 I found your answer the fastest. I don't think it can get any better. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @ahmohamed: I'm currently doing a few tests to make sure I can post something that works properly on edge cases like `[1, 1, 1]`, where `c[-1]/2 == 1` and `numpy.searchsorted(c, c[-1]/2) == 0`.

Comment: @ahmohamed: This is turning out to have way more horrible edge cases than I was hoping for. For example, `a=[1.1, 2.2, 0.0, 2.2, 1.1]` needs to produce an index of 2, but due to rounding error, I'm getting 1, and I'm not sure how to handle the issue in a correct and efficient way.

Comment: @ahmohamed: At this point, I have 5 test cases and 40 lines of text, mostly tests and comments, trying to make sure the binary search does the right thing in all cases. Considering that the runtime difference is only a constant factor, I would go for chw21's second version, which explicitly minimizes the difference between the left and right sums. Also, I would make sure this thing has comprehensive test cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2357112, I really appreciate it. It would be great if you could you post your test cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can find equilibrium point from below code

```
    a = [1,3,5,2,2]
b = equilibirum(a)
n = len(a)
first_sum = 0
last_sum = 0
if n==1:
    print (1)
    return 0
for i in range(n):
    first_sum=first_sum+a[i]
    for j in range(i+2,n):
        last_sum=last_sum+a[j]
    if first_sum ==last_sum:
        s=i+2
        print (s)
        return 0
    last_sum=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is what I got, but I am not sure it is that fastest way:

```
def eq(a)
    c = np.cumsum(a)
    return sum(c <= c[-1]/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two '3's in your array. Seems to me like maybe you should return the index of the desired element, instead of its value, just to know which 3 is the actual equilibrium? In this particular example it would be:

```
f(a) = 4 # (because a[4] = 3)
```

instead of:

```
f(a) = 3
```

If that's the case, here's my proposition how to define a proper function:

```
def equi(arr):
  length = len(arr)
  if length == 0: return -1
  if length == 1: return 0

  i = 1
  j = 0 

  # starting sum1 (the 'left' sum)
  sum1 = 0

  # starting sum2 (the 'right' sum)
  sum2 = sum(arr[1:])

  while j < length:
      if sum1 == sum2: return j
      if j == length-1:
        sum2 = 0
      else:
        sum1 += arr[j]
        sum2 -= arr[j+1]
      j += 1
  if sum1 != 0: return -1
```

ps. this is my frist ever contribution on stack overflow and I'm a begginer in programming. Please, feel free to comment on my solution if it's not a good one!